# Why variables are not set

Tags: batch-file

I have a file report.txt having comma separated values like (1,2,3,4). I am checking if the file is not blank then assign the 4 variables with values in the file. But the variables are not set. Any help why this is happening?

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    for /f %%i in ("Report.txt") do set size=%%~zi 
    if %size% gtr 0 (

    for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%A in ("Report.txt") do (
        set "var1=%%a"
        set "var2=%%b"
        set "var3=%%c"
        set "var4=%%d"

    )
    set var
    )
    echo %var1%
```

Comment: If you are trying to read in the contents of Report.txt then you need to use the USEBACKQ option because you have the file name in quotes.

Comment: Alternatively, you could simply remove the quotes from the file name.

Comment: Doh!!!! Case Sensitive FOR variables.

Comment: Of course! The _one time_ variables are case-sensitive in batch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've enabled delayed expansion, but you aren't using it. In order to use delayed expansion, you need to use `!variable!` instead of `%variable%`. Additionally, the variable specified in `for` loops is case-sensitive, so you either need to set var1 equal to `%%A` or use `%%a` as the loop variable.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f %%i in ("Report.txt") do set size=%%~zi 
if %size% gtr 0 (

    for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%a in (Report.txt) do (
        set "var1=%%a"
        set "var2=%%b"
        set "var3=%%c"
        set "var4=%%d"
    )
    set var
)
echo !var1!
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had tried that but the echo output is %a instead of the expected output as 1

Comment: @bob If you are trying to read in the contents of Report.txt then you need to use the USEBACKQ option because you have the file name in quotes.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just remove the quotes from the file name.

Comment: Thank for your time. I tried both removing the quotes and for /F " USEBACKQ tokens=1-4 delims=," %%A in ("Report.txt") do (  but both didn't work. Removing the quotes makes the code hang and adding USEBACKQ  gives the same output as %a instead of 1

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f %%i in ("Report.txt") do set size=%%~zi 
if %size% gtr 0 (
```

I changed the code as below and it started working. Thank you guys for your time. Appeciate it.

```
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%A in (%cd%\Report.txt) do (
    set "var1=%%A"
    set "var2=%%B"
    set "var3=%%C"
    set "var4=%%D"    

)
set var
)
echo !var1!
```

Comment: seems like it would have been easier to change your FOR variable to lower case instead of changing all the SET statements.  ;)

Comment: Also would have been easier to accept my answer instead of writing this one since they're practically identical.

Comment: Thanks you guys for your help and giving your time in explaining all this. I am very new to batch programming but learning from all these posts. Appreciate it.